# Is there a way to not affect non manifold edges by sculpt bruhes.?

Tags: sculpting

I have a big landscape modell (golf course) with an lot of non-manifold edges (everytime when a lawn is next to a hard surface). Now - i want to sculpt the greens, roughs, bunkers and so on. but when i come near or over an non manifold edge it is moved away from its original positon -

is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: You could hide them or join them, if joining works.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1809/599

Answer (score 1):

I'd try adding those vertices to a vertex group and then using a mask modifier with this group as the modifiers target.

Comment: this did not work - you can sculpt in the area which is masked out. you see the results when you leave the sculpt mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the *Mask* brush (or any of the other mask tools available in *Header > Hide/Mask*) to paint areas which you don't want to affect:

[image]

Comment: this works very well - is there a method to convert a mesh selection into mask aereas? because on a complex surface it will be very easy to select non manifold edges- expand selection and make mask of the frist row of faces.

Comment: @Rosebarb Not that I know of. That would be a useful feature though..

Comment: some detail i find in your screenshot: lasso or box mask is not in default blender - plz can you tell me add on or version number of your blender?

Comment: @Rosebarb It should be there by default.. The above screenshot is a development build, maybe that's why. Try 2.69 or a dev build.